# Algebraic manipulation of a limit.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

What are the algebraic manipulations and steps that makes the limit

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to2}\left(\frac{x^3-8}{x-2}\right)
\end{equation}

equal to

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to2}(x^2+2x+4)
\end{equation}

It's probably trivial, I just don't seem to be able to see it.

Comment: Factorisation. $~~$

Comment: This follows from the factoring of a difference of cubes. i.e., $x^3-8 = (x-2)(x^2+2x+4)$.

Comment: note that $x^3-8=(x^3-2x^2)+(2x^2-4x)+(4x-8)$

Answer (score 4):

Use $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ formula

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Kushal Bhuyan hint

> Use $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ formula

In our case

$$\lim_{x\to2}\left(\frac{x^3-8}{x-2}\right)
=\lim_{x\to2}\left(\frac{x^3-2^3}{x-2}\right)
$$

Then $x^3-2^3=(x-2)(x^2+2x+2^2)$, therefore:

$$\require{cancel}\lim_{x\to2}\left(\frac{\cancel{(x-2)}(x^2+2x+2^2)}{\cancel{x-2}}\right)
=\lim_{x\to2}(x^2+2x+4)=2^2+2\cdot 2+4=\color{blue}{12}$$

Comment: +1 the only answer to make the connection for the OP that $8\ = 2^3$

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{x^3-8}{x-2}$$
$$x^3-8\Rightarrow(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)$$
$$=\dfrac{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)}{x-2}$$
$$=x^2+2x+4$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this without knowing $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$. 
You can always apply polynomial long division in such fractions:

$$(x^3-8):(x-2)=x^2+2x+4$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are ignorant of the factorization formula for the difference of two cubes, you have to rediscover it.

From the problem statement, you know that $x^3-8$ has a root at $x=2$. Then the binomial will factor as

$$x^3-8=(x-2)P_2(x)$$ where $P_2$ is a quadratic trinomial. We can obtain it by long division

$$\begin{matrix}&1&0&0&-8\\2|&&2&4&8\\&1&2&4&0\end{matrix},$$ giving

$$x^3-8=(x-2)(x^2+2x+4).$$

The limit easily follows as $2^2+2\cdot2+4$.